# Integrating an arbitrary function

Tags: integration

I am trying  to integrate the function $f(r)$ from $\vec r_0$ to $\vec r$ which is parametrised by $\vec r^\prime = \lambda\vec r$ with $0\le\lambda\le1$. Thus $d\vec r^\prime=d\lambda\vec r$.

$f(r)$ is an arbitrary function of $r=|\vec r|$.

Ignoring the limits of integration, how can I perform the integral:
$$\int f(\lambda r)\:d\lambda$$

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is your question too general? I mean, one could have $f_1(r) = e^{-r^2}$ versus $f_2(r) = 2r$ and then the question is massively different. Different techniques of integration apply depending precisely on the integrand. In fact, in the former example it is impossible to express the integral in elementary functions.

Comment: @palindromicprime Interesting, it seems that I will have to leave the integral as it is unless I am not given the specific function that $f(r)$ represents.